# Python latest print format with list comprehension using the items() method

Tags: python-3.6

As an avid learner i'm working with dictionaries and took an example below code, I'm just curious to Know what will be correct syntactic way of print format instead what i'm using `print("Age For", d,":",v)`

```
   >>> ageDict = {'Tony': '21', 'Mony': '22'}
    >>> for d, v in ageDict.items():
    ...     print("Age For", d,":",v)
    ...
    Age For Tony : 21
    Age For Mony : 22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good idea is two use the recently introduced `F""` syntax:

```
for d, v in ageDict.items():
    print(F"Age For {d}: {v}")
```

or

```
for i in ageDict.items():
    print(F"Age For {i[0]}: {i[1]}")
```

Comment: @ tif,  nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing syntactically incorrect with using a loop like you do, but if you're looking to do it with a list comprehension or generator expression you can do:

```
print('\n'.join(f'Age For {k}: {v}' for k, v in ageDict.items()))
```

Comment: @ blhsing, nice one.